# How to convert UTC timezone to local timezone location

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, momentjs

I have following Code:

```
UTC<br/>
<div id="divUTC">'UTC+5:30'</div><br/>
<br/>
<div id="divLocal">
</div>
```

In My javascript I am trying to convert UTC+5:30 to IST-Indian Standard Time (Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi)
UTC value could be anything so does the converted value.

```
var divUtc = $('#divUTC');
var divLocal = $('#divLocal');  

//get text from divUTC and convert to local timezone
```

I know i have not placed any code here, But sorry its not hitting my mind, I have option of putting key-value pairs but that's not effective. Please suggest.

Comment: timezone  conversion is a relatively big effort. I'd advice to use some library like [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) for it

Comment: Hi Vladimir M, i understand, but momentjs is having only converting UTC time to local time, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems of converting UTC+XX to whatever local timezone text is that it is not 1:1 mapping. Still, if you use momentjs with time zones, you could get yourself a list of possible locations.

1) get all the known timezones:

```
var names = moment.tz.names();
// names now contain an array of tz names
```

2) iterate over names array, create moment object in particular timezone and get its offset. Following code will print the offssets for each tz name for this moment.

```
for( var i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
    console.log(moment.tz(names[i]).format('Z'));
}
```

3) within that loop you may compare the utcOffset of the moment or textual representation of the offset and get a set of timezones that fit your offset.

Here is a loop that will print all the tz names for +05:30.

```
var names = moment.tz.names();
for( var i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
    if(moment.tz(names[i]).format('Z') === "+05:30"){
        console.log(names[i])    
    }
}

// output:
//     Asia/Calcutta
//     Asia/Colombo
//     Asia/Kolkata
```

Also, keep in mind that many regions have DST time changes, meaning that region may have a different offset depending on the time of the year.